# XmlHttpRequest not working on Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, ajax, mobile

```
function ajaxify()
    {
     alert('stuff');
     xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlHttp.open('GET', 'page.php?params=' + params, true);
     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction;
     xmlHttp.send();

    }

function callbackFunction(){
alert('called');
}
```

Never alerts "called", but does alert "stuff". Testing on iPhone 4.2.1 and Windows 7 Phone. Doesn't work on either. I'm told it works on newer phones. Works on desktop browser. The page is loaded, but the callbackFunction is never called. Any way of fixing this?

EDIT: Note, I also tried `xmlHttp.onload`, seems like the same issue.

Comment: Not really an answer, but is there any particular reason why you don't use an abstraction layer, such as jquery for this. It takes care of all the kinks and oddities that you otherwise have to find and debug your self.

Comment: I'm not particularly good at javascript, what would I use something like `$('#hidden').load('api.php?params=params', function() {
  alert('The rest of my code goes here referencing #hidden to get the contents of the file I just loaded?');
});`

Comment: I also have the same problem with my application. Stone cold not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error. forgot `'` after `params=`:

```
xmlHttp.open( 'GET', 'page.php?params="' + params, true)
```

Comment: Woops, that was just a typo when I removed the params to post here. That does not appear to be the issue.

Comment: Sorry mate, couldn't find anything about this one.. I recommend you try using some framework ajax such as jquery (only to see if there's a problem with ajax generally or just with this specific code..)